# Converting decimal list to binary python

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a code that I am working on. I have run into a problem where I cannot figure out a way to convert a list I have in decimal to binary. I have searched for examples, but cannot find a solution. If you could help me out with a way to handle this way specifically that would be great thanks.

Code

```
PT = input("Please enter your plaintext: ")
PT = PT.lower()
K = input("Please enter your key: ")
K = K.lower()
output1 = []
output2 = []
for character in PT:
    if character.isdigit():
        digit = ord(character) - 22
        output1.append(digit)
    elif character.isalpha():
        number = ord(character) - 97
        output1.append(number)
    else:
        print("Please use letters and numbers only. (Plaintext)")
        break

for character in K:
    if character.isdigit():
        digit = ord(character) - 22
        output2.append(digit)
    elif character.isalpha():
        number = ord(character) - 97
        output2.append(number)
    else:
        print("Please use letters and numbers only. (Key)")
        break
```

Comment: Took multiple times to fix the indent issues.

Comment: You should use raw_input instead of input. [The differences between input and raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: I'm actually on python 3.5.0 so wouldn't raw_input just be input now? or am I mistaken @Sphinx

Comment: In python 3, they are same. What is the problem you met? Can you provide more details?

Comment: This is what I received when I replaced input with raw_input ------------------------------------------------------------------line 1, in <module>
    PT = raw_input("Please enter your plaintext: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: May bad because I am running on 2.7. But I am still confuse what problem you met.

Comment: When I run my program it outputs in a list the ascii values of the string input. It will subtract 22 or 97 if its a number or letter respectfully. I want to know how to convert that ascii value from its current state (decimal) to binary.

Comment: Try use bin(number/char).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bin() to convert the object to the binary.

```
PT = raw_input("Please enter your plaintext: ")
PT = PT.lower()
K = raw_input("Please enter your key: ")
output1 = []
output2 = []
for character in PT:
    if character.isdigit():
        digit = ord(character) - 22
        output1.append(bin(digit))
    elif character.isalpha():
        number = ord(character) - 97
        output1.append(bin(number))
    else:
        print("Please use letters and numbers only. (Plaintext)")
        break
for character in K:
    if character.isdigit():
        digit = ord(character) - 22
        output2.append(bin(digit))
    elif character.isalpha():
        number = ord(character) - 97
        output2.append(bin(number))
    else:
        print("Please use letters and numbers only. (Key)")
        break
print output1
print output2
```

**Test case:**

Please enter your plaintext: abc

Please enter your key: 234

['0b0', '0b1', '0b10']

['0b11100', '0b11101', '0b11110']